# Go Stomp client for ActiveMQ

Tags: go, activemq-classic, stomp

Is there a active Stomp client library for connecting to ActiveMQ using Go?
[Go-Stomp](https://github.com/go-stomp/stomp) is last updated 8 months ago.
I just started using it and ran into few problems such as

- no support for failover syntax (not a show stopper)
- Caching connection missing
- Can not check if a connection is closed or not. One has to compare the error returned from **Send** method.

Before I continue to use it for production system, want to check if there is a preferred stomp client in Go other than Go-Stomp?